# Xamarin Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin application running on Windows, and I have a method which includes an opening of a pdf file like this:

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
{
     FileName = "cmd",
     WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
     UseShellExecute = false,
     CreateNoWindow = true,
     Arguments = $"/c start {filename}"
};
Process.Start(psi);
```

When this executes, the windows opens a dialog with the following message:

> Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item.

The filename is a pdf file located in the LocalApplicationData, and I also have a database there, and the application is normally creating a database there and manipulates with it, so it should have a permission to access that folder. Also, when I run that pdf with double-click outside the application, the pdf opens normally with Chrome. How to solve this?

Comment: there are a lot of existing similar questions - https://www.google.com/search?q=processstartinfo+Windows+cannot+access+the+specified+device+site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a file there called "cmd" this won't work, as you have declared your filename as a string with the value "cmd".